# Grid VS Cloud Architecture?

Tags: architecture, grid, cloud

From reading on the Internet it seems to me that Grids are peer to peer systems while the cloud is (at least in most cases) a client-server system. Yet I haven’t seen this point beeing made. Am I incorrect in thinking this?

From most Grid examples I have seen, several computers provide and request data from each other. Hence they act both as clients and servers (peers). Most cloud examples I have seen are simply companies offering resources (processing resources) to clients. It might be that the server in a cloud service uses something more complicated, like for example a grid, but it still seems like a client-server architecture to me.

So my question is:
Is the grid a p2p system while the cloud is a client-server system?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:
1st part: NO: Grid applications typically are not P2P.
2nd part: YES: Cloud is a client-server system.

Longer answer:
1st part: A grid application typically (but not exclusively) consists of a mass of client applications distributed to and executed on the individual computers making up the "grid". The work load of these clients is typically controlled by one (or more) central servers who segment and parcel the overall workload into pieces to be executed by one or more of the grid nodes. Thsese central instances also collect back the results provides by the external nodes.

2nd part: From point of view of an application or user connecting to a cloud (SaaS) application, SaaS indeed looks like a C/S application. Note that the architecture WITHIN the cloud application (everything behind the IP address endpoint) is COMPLETELY DIFFERENT from a typical three tier C/S application.